# How to define 'x' to be anything in mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory

/profilepics/x

where x is any number

Is there any way I can redirect the user with mod_rewrite to another page no matter what the number or extension is?

I tried this

RewriteRule ^$ /profilepics/(.*)$ [L]

but that didnt work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I've misunderstood but I think this is what you're after:

```
RewriteRule ^profilepics/(.*)$ page_to_redirect_to.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The above example will redirect any request for `mydomain.com/profilepics/*` onto `page_to_redirect_to.php`

**UPDATE**

I've updated the code to pass the part of the URL after `profilepics/` onto the page in a GET var called `url`...just in case you need to know how that's done.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks my layout when if the page is from that redirect, it loads certain div's more than once and the page never stops loading :S but this does what I asked for, thanks :)

Comment: @Update that fixed it, apart from the image thumbnail script which is pretty broken anyway haha, Thanks a tonne